# Retrieve only a certain byte range from a file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is this possible?  I'm thinking it should be as long as the server supports resume (HTTP RANGE).

Comment: The server doesn't know what you want unless you tell it to.  Make your server understand that you only want a certain byte range for the response.  Ajax is simply there to read the response and use it in-script.  So, this isn't really a matter of Ajax.  Unless you want to filter the whole response once retrieved.

Comment: @Jamen, yes, and I want to "tell it" using the HTTP RANGE command. How to do this is the question.

Comment: I think you just have to set the `RANGE` header with AJAX. Answer with code coming up!

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: @charlietfl Read a line from a large fixed-width file on a CDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()) to set the `RANGE` request header:

```
//Our AJAX object:
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open([REQUEST METHOD], [REQUEST URI], true);
//Set the RANGE header here:
req.setRequestHeader("RANGE", "value-of-RANGE-header");
// [Here, set anything else you need before sending the request, like onstatechange]
//Now, send!
req.send();
```

Comment: I get `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` in Chrome.  Also, you have a capitalization error in `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Nm, works with proper `Content-Type` response from server, thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!

Comment: learn something new every day...didn't know this could be done